# How to enable coordinates of a point as a input

Tags: java

I recently started developing a basic *"Battleship"* game in *Java*.

I've already created the match-field containing the position of each ship. Now, I'd like to allow the user to provide the program with a coordinate. If the coordinate in question is overlapping with the position of a ship, then that particular ship should be removed out of the `ships` queue.

I already tried out the `Scanner` class in the `java.util` package to no avail. It would be great if someone could please help me with interpreting a two-dimensional coordinate in a text-based stream. The syntax of a coordinate should be as follows: `x, y`. Pretty straight forward, right?

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Position ships.
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).next();
    List<Point> ships = new ArrayList<>(5);
    ships.add(new Point(2, 1));
    ships.add(new Point(3, 2));
    ships.add(new Point(10, 4));
    ships.add(new Point(7, 6));
    ships.add(new Point(8, 4));
    while(true)
    {
        // Check status.
        if(ships.length > 0)
        {
            // Check if a field is containing a ship.
            for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
                {
                    if (ships.contains(new Point(x, y)))
                    {
                        System.out.print('S');
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        System.out.print('.');
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            // TODO: Query the input of the user.
            final String input = scanner.next();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You won the game!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To answer the question in the title, you ask the user for two integers.  Whether they are typed by the user on the same line or different lines is up to you.  I suggest using the Scanner readLine method and processing what the user types on the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) object to get the player input
2. Read x and y values
3. Check if is hit or not

Hint: Put the steps 2 and 3 in a loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point[] shipPositions = new Point[5];
    shipPositions[0] = new Point(2, 1);
    shipPositions[1] = new Point(3, 2);
    shipPositions[2] = new Point(10, 4);
    shipPositions[3] = new Point(7, 6);
    shipPositions[4] = new Point(8, 4);

    //Player input
    System.out.println("Coordinates needed");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x, y;

    System.out.print("x=");
    x = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("y=");
    y = in.nextInt();

    Point p = new Point(x, y);

    if (Arrays.asList(shipPositions).contains(p)) {
        System.out.print("Hit");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Miss");
    }
}
```

Example

```
Coordinates needed
x=2
y=1
Hit
```